# How can I export products with cross or up-sells products?

Tags: product, export, up-sells, cross-sells, magento-1.5

In admin section (`System->Import/Export`) new Import/Export variant. If I use export all products and nothing have cross or up sells product, then export working fine. But if have any products cross or up sells products export not working.

How can I export products with cross or up-sells products?

Comment: I haven't tried Magmi, but I keep hearing that it is better.

Have you tried System->Import/Export-> Dataflow Profiles
Select the Profile Export All Products.
Here are a few links that show step by step.

[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles)
[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/export_tool)
[link](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/import-products.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I personally use Magmi for all imports

> http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Under their Product Import Related Plugins, they have a **crosssell / upsell importer** :

> http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Cross/Upsell_Importer

Answer (score 3):

I got them from database directly. It is the fastest and most reliable solution for me.

You can find the sql query for upsells.

upsell type id = 4 
crosssell type id = 5

```
SELECT cpe.sku AS sku, cpe2.sku AS us_sku
FROM  `catalog_product_link` AS cpl, catalog_product_entity AS cpe,catalog_product_entity AS cpe2
WHERE cpl.link_type_id =4
AND cpl.product_id = cpe.entity_id
AND cpl.linked_product_id = cpe2.entity_id
```

Hope this works.

Cheers

Comment: Just wanted to add to this, `cpl.link_type_id =1` is relational products

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to **export** related/cross-sell/upsell products I don't think you can do this through default Dataflow profile functionality.

If you consider paid solution check out [this](http://productuploader.magelynx.com) one

In there, in order to export you need to add fields **"sku", "re_skus", "cs_skus", "us_skus"** (for related products, cross-sells and up-sells correspondingly) to your CSV Spreadsheet and then filter your products in Magento product grid and run export - it will populate your CSV.